# How to count total hours

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Following is my table [image]

I want to calculate total hours of current month there are few columns on table **working_hours, working_mint** so i want to count total hrs of current month using this two column .

I used following query but it's not showing well output.

```
SELECT (SUM( working_hour )*60) + SUM( working_minit ) as AM
FROM task_details
WHERE MONTH(task_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(task_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
AND task_id=7797 AND member_id=92
```

I need hours like 4 or 8 etc
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean `it's not showing well output.`

Comment: I mean it's given wrong calculate hrs

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY YEAR(task_date), MONTH(task_date)`  Sum is an aggregate function.  `total hours of current month` implies you should have 1 column returned.

Comment: Yes but its return outpu like 1275

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: value retun 1275

Comment: So?  That means what to me.  Value returned from what?

Comment: 1275 may be in minute

Comment: I want only total hours with minute for example . 4.45 hrs

Comment: then just make `SELECT ((SUM( working_hour )*60) + SUM( working_minit )) /60 as AM`